# Rename a Lumen project (5.5)

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Hopefully this is quite an easy question, but I've struggled to find any answers elsewhere.
All I would like to do is rename my Lumen project (v 5.5), how would I do this? I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration).

I've tried using the following command from [old Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#after-installation), with no success:

```
php artisan app:name
```

There doesn't seem to be anywhere to rename the project in the .env file like other answers online have suggested.
I've also tried renaming the folder manually which just broke the whole API.

Thanks for your help in advance, and hopefully I've not just missed something obvious!

Comment: The `app:name` command in Laravel just changes the root namespace.

Comment: @MartinBean Ah yes I see, do you know if there is any way to rename the entire project? Or would it be a case of creating a new project and copying code over?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rename a Lumen project"? Rename the folder it is installed in?

Comment: @kerbholz Yeah sorry, the same name that would be assigned in "lumen new blog" - how would I go about changing "blog" after the project has been created?

Comment: you can change the APP_NAME variable in the .env file

Comment: `lumen new blog` creates a new lumen project in the folder `blog`. Just rename that folder

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala There is no `APP_NAME` in `.env` in Lumen

Comment: oh.. sorry.. I thought it was Laravel

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks a lot for your help so far - when I rename that folder I just get a load of 404 errors on my API. Is there a command I need to use to 'serve' (in search for better words) the new folder?

Comment: Also make sure to stop your running `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` and restart it from the newly renamed folder

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala My tag probably confused you, my bad

Comment: @kerbholz That's what I was looking for, thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, have fun with Lumen ;)

Comment: fyi, I added my comments as answer so people with the same problem can find the solution faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lumen` doesn't have an "app name" like `Laravel` does. All you need to do is rename the folder you installed your `Lumen` project in.

Make sure to stop your PHP server if it is running, change (`cd`) to your newly renamed folder and start it again using `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`.